# I have a Date in String 20090422 110126000 format yyyymmdd hh24miss 20090422 110126000

Tags: java, date, gwt

I have a Date in String in gwt.
This date is stored as String in oracle database format is 
//format yyyymmdd hh24miss.
On java/gwt side I want to change the format to yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.SSS

```
String dateString = '20090422 110126000' //format yyyymmdd hh24miss.
```

How to convert it into this format yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.SSS.
Im not been able to find the correct format to parse the string in Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it using this date format, like

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd hhmmssSSS");
System.out.println(dateFormat.parse("20090422 110126000"));
```

Which will give you this output

```
Wed Apr 22 11:01:26 CEST 2009
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use GWT [DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/DateTimeFormat.html) class to parse any String and to format the resulting Date.

Answer (score 1):

```
//From String to Date
String dateString = '20090422 110126000'
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd hhmmssSS");
Date date = format.parse(dateString);

//From Date to String
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
String finalDate = df.format(date);
```

Comment: Correct answer for Java, but not for GWT.